# Excel - Convert one time format to another

Tags: php, sql, excel, filemtime

I'm trying to migrate data from one application to another via SQL imports, and I'm at the final step of grabbing the date of entry. The difficulty I'm experiencing is that the date is in some odd format.

Examples are as follows...
1360938606
1360938612
1360938607
1360938607

In the new application, the date format is as follows:
0000-00-00 00:00:00

Is there a way that I can convert the original format to this new format in Excel?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a unix timestamp value rather than an Excel timestamp value: 1360938606 is 2013-02-15

Comment: That's what I was thinking.

Comment: So how are you writing to Excel?

Comment: Well, I did an export of the data from the database (into a CSV) and I'm doing all of the mapping manually (in an excel document). As a result, I'm trying to find a way to convert the Unix timestamp to the format posted above (essentially YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: If you're just writing CSV, then a simple date('Y-m-d',1360938606) watch out for potential timezone issues with unix timestamps; if you're writing OfficeOpenXML (xlsx) or BIFF (xls) then your library should provide date conversion functions to write Excel timestamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this :

```
$newdateformat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $oldtimestamp);
```

refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Looks like unix timestamp ad Mark mentioned... which is actually pretty standard. You can use `strftime` from php to convert it to the string format you want:

`$time = strftime('%F %T', (int) $thevalue)`